# Rewriting URL's Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok this is something that's been driving me nuts for a while now. There is plenty of information out there on how to rewrite URL's using .htaccess files out there. But for some reason after hours of trying I still haven't managed to have any effect on my urls. I've tried moving directives to the apache2.conf, still no luck. I'm not great at server admin stuff but i'm getting there. I do notice though that tons of sites out there, ones probably built by web designers etc wordpress sites or what have you, even they have clean urls.

So AFAIK all i need to do is paste in one of these mod rewrite rules e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to a file named .htaccess in my public_html directory. For some reason this does not work for me. I'm using digital ocean so theres a chance i've missed some crucial step setting up my LAMP server as I said i'm still coming to grips with server admin. Any help or suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Clean URLs"? .php not showing at the end? Having things like site.com/home point to home.php, site.com/faq point to faq.php and so on but without folders? The websites you're mentioning probably have URLs like that because they're using frameworks or CMS and they have dynamic data, not just for looking good.

Comment: Your .htaccess works just fine for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm talking about any kind of rewrite. From removing a .php to redirecting an old page

Comment: I guess the real question is, is it safe to assume pasting in these rewrite directives in will just work, or is this something you have to actually understand and be familiar with apache for. And is there anything ive potentially missed cause so far nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

With most php frameworks (wordpress, laravel, etc), all url requests that are not 'real' directories or files are redirected to a single entry point. eg. `index.php`, Where the request is processed and the page is displayed accordingly.

Here is a simple example where all requests that are not actual directories or files are redirected to index.php and processed:

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    default:
        echo "404: Page cannot be found";
        break;
    case 'page1':
        echo "This is page 1";
        break;
    case 'page2':
        echo "This is page 2";
        break;  
    case 'page3':
        echo "This is page 3";
        break;      
}
```

So if you go to http://somedomain.com/page1 it will show "This is page 1". If you go to http://somedomain.com/page4 it will show "404: Page cannot be found".

Comment: Thats the front controller design pattern. All requests are handled by a single controller (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller)